# Displaying live data to UI

Tags: java, user-interface, logic

I have a main class where the UI is located and that it instantiates another class, where the logic is located. I create the instance of the logic only when a button is clicked.

```
private void computeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        //A STAR MISPLACED
        EightPuzzle ep2 = new EightPuzzle(stringToInt(initial),"mis");
        solution = ep2.getSolution();
        aMisplacedSpace.setText(ep2.getNodesTraversed()+" nodes");  // I would like to display this during the search and not just after
        setCurrentTilesAStarMisplaced(solution.size()-1);
}
```

The problem is that I have to display the number of nodes traversed during a particular instance into some JLabel in the UI. I guess my current structure does not allow me to do so.  Is there a work around on this?

Comment: Im the only one missing something ? What structure ? what instance ? What work around ?

Comment: @wrongAnswer The structure I was referring to is the separation of the UI class and the logic of the program. ep2 is the instance. And i was thinking if there are any workaround regarding the structure.